Notification Icon Background Color Appears Different in Android Notification (Expected #00BFFF, Shows as #1DA1F2)
I'm working on a notification for my Android app, and I've set a custom background color for the notification icon. The color I expect to see is #00BFFF (a light blue), but the icon appears with a different color, #1DA1F2, which is a darker shade of blue.
I've defined the color in my drawable and referenced it in the notification as follows:
    val notificationBuilder =
        NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHAT_CHANNEL_ID)
//                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(
                    context,
                    R.color.notification_color
                )
            ) // #00BFFF but it shows like #1DA1F2
    ```

